# Does Snowflake provide cost information in explain plan to SQL clients like DataGrip?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datagrip

I've noticed that when I query my Postgres database, DataGrip allows me to examine the explain plain (operations tree, Flame chart, visual graph) with operation, row, and cost information.

When I run (any) query on Snowflake, DataGrip returns an explain plan with the basic operations but no information on cost. I'm thinking that it is **not** returning information *ex post* query execution.

Is this expected behavior? [This](https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00008nQdYSSA0/how-can-i-get-query-plan-information-programatically) post makes me think that Snowflake doesn't support this outside of their GUI.

Comment: Q: What does "cost" even mean in Snowflake (vs. in a more "traditional" RDBMS like PostgreSQL  or Oracle)?  Q: Have you tried [SYSTEM$EXPLAIN_PLAN_JSON](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_explain_plan_json.html), as referenced in your post?  Does it have the information you're looking for?

Comment: Issue in DataGrip project: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-10557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in Snowflake 'cost' is  partition bytes in optimizer and we don't show them. But if you think it would be useful - feel free to fill up feature request on [our tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE).